# Compiling caffe

Tags: cmake, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to compile caffe using cmake on a Linux machine.  I get this complaint when running cmake:

```
 Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is at least version "2.7")
```

I later get this error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:85 (add_dependencies):
  The dependency target "pycaffe" of target "pytest" does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?  I tried setting an environment variable for PYTHON_LIBRARIES but that didn't help.  I'm using my locally installed version of python (2.7.13), so I think that might be causing the problem, but I don't know how to get past this.

Comment: Have you installed the `python-dev` (or `python-devel`) package? If not, do `apt-get install python-dev`...

Comment: I installed python from source code.  I can not run apt-get because I don't have root access.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to "fix it" by editing the file build/CMakeCache.txt and manually setting these

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
PYTHON_LIBRARY
```

I don't know if that's the correct way to resolve this. If not, what is the right way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while installing caffe on Ubuntu 14.04; I solved this by installing boost-python:

sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully through the installation instructions.  There's a variety of dependencies to install (python-devel, glog-devel, ...) and some environment variables to set.  Using a local Python installation isn't a problem, as long as you have that properly in your paths.  Remember to check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables as well.

You might check with

```
env | egrep -i "py"
```

to see what variables *do* have Python references.  If you suspect a version problem with an executable, use

```
ldd <executable>
```

To see what objects and versions get loaded.  Among other things, it's vaguely possible that something got compiled against an older Python in the system directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install numpy

Try `pip install numpy`

Answer (score 0):

I have met this problem and finally solve it by `pip install numpy`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).